# How to get computers and printers on WiFi to access computers and printers on ethernet, and vice versa?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, ethernet, file-sharing

I am a programmer with server management experience but lacking in network training. By default, I've been given responsibility for the company network ("computer guy must know ALL computer things"). I've searched Superuser but haven't found answers that are relevant. Though, I'm not sure about the correct terms to use.

**The Problem**

We can't get everyone to share files between computers and printers. We have an ethernet network and 2 wireless networks. Some users and printers are connected through ethernet, many use the WiFi network.

We have two WiFi networks--one for company and one for guests. We do on-site training and have printers connected to the guest WiFi. However, employees use both WiFi networks because some printers on the guest network are closer to their offices. We also have computers and printers on the other WiFi network and a few on ethernet that WiFi users can't access.

I've tried getting everyone off the guest network but have been overridden on that. I don't like company computers on the guest network. Makes me nervous.

**The Hardware**

Our office computers are all relatively new Macs (2-3 yrs old). They should just connect to the network and "see" the other computers but only a few show up--maybe a printer or one or two computers.

We have a Comcast business router - no specific brand on it (?).

Our building is about 6k sqft and is very long (only about 40ft wide) so they added a Linksys Velop mesh WiFi kit (a base unit and 2 extender units).

**The Question**

How do I get everyone to "see" and access all the assets in the whole office, on ethernet and WiFi?

Any ideas or thoughts on this will be helpful. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: "Our building is about 6k sqft and is very long (only about 40ft wide) so they added a Linksys Velop mesh WiFi kit "  <--- that is fairly big and needs lots of wireless coverage. Make sure wireless subnets are on the same subnet as wired devices. Ask for support in the form of a network consultant to guide you.

Comment: Do employees have admin-level access to their own Macs?  If not, I think that means they can't add Printers on their own.  One solution might be to remove admin-level access and reconfigure the company's Macs to use the non-Guest-wifi printers only.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify, the Wi-Fi devices need to be Access Point, so there will be only one subnet.

Check the IP addresses on computers/printers connected to ethernet, and IP addresses on computer/printers connected to Wi-Fi. They need to be in the same subnet, so for example if the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 and the IP address of one computer connected to ethernet is 192.168.1.15, then all IP addresses (ethernet or Wi-Fi) must begin with "192.168.1".

If the Wi-Fi devices you have are routers, you must set them to Access Point mode.

Comment: If the devices are routers but don't have a dedicated "Access Point mode" one may replicate that as follows. First, the uplink ethernet cable of that wifi router should be plugged into the switch port, instead of the "WAN" port. Finally, the DHCP server should be turned off.